# Php upon success submition function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to display popup box upon successful submit of form and a function to stay on the page or redirect back to previous page.

Here is my code:

```
if ($success) { 
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
   header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
}
?>
```

With the above code, popup is not showing but page stays upon successful submit but it does't show alert.

Comment: does the page redirect to history?

Comment: No, It stays on the same page

Comment: Then the issue is with the value of `$success`. It must not be `true`. Quickly try this: `if ($success) { 
echo "hello world";
} `

Comment: No, I do not need echo message to show, i need alert box to show and page redirect to previous page.

Comment: are you sure your $success is true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try javascript code to redirect back page instead of php header function:

```
if ($success) { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='javascript:history.go(-1)'; </script>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is running after the page have loaded, while javascript runs when the page has loaded.
try something like this:

```
if ($success) { 
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='javascript:history.go(-1)'; </script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Never use `javascript:` URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open#Never_use_this_form_of_code_for_links%3a.3Ca_href.3D.22javascript%3awindow.open.28....29.22_....3E)!

If you want to simulate clicking the back button in the browser, the correct syntax is to directly call the JavaScript function [`history.go(-1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history) (or the equivalent `history.back()`). To trigger this from PHP, try something like this:

```
<?php if ($success) { ?>
    <script>history.go(-1);</script>
<?php } ?>
```